# SQL Join to only the maximum row puzzle

Tags: sql, mysql, join

Given the following example data:

```
  Users
+--------------------------------------------------+
| ID | First Name | Last Name | Network Identifier |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | Billy      | O'Neal    | bro4               |
+----+------------+-----------+--------------------+
| 2  | John       | Skeet     | jsk1               |
+----+------------+-----------+--------------------+

 Hardware
+----+-------------------+---------------+
| ID | Hardware Name     | Serial Number |
+----------------------------------------+
| 1  | Latitude E6500    | 5555555       |
+----+-------------------+---------------+
| 2  | Latitude E6200    | 2222222       |
+----+-------------------+---------------+

 HardwareAssignments
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| User ID | Hardware ID | Assigned On |
+-------------------------------------+
| 1       | 1           | April 1     |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 1       | 2           | April 10    |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 2       | 2           | April 1     |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 2       | 1           | April 11    |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

I'd like to write a SQL query which would give the following result:

```
+--------------------+------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+-------------+
| Network Identifier | First Name | Last Name | Hardware Name  | Serial Number | Assigned On |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| bro4               | Billy      | O'Neal    | Latitude E6200 | 2222222       | April 10    |
+--------------------+------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+-------------+
| jsk1               | John       | Skeet     | Latitude E6500 | 5555555       | April 11    |
+--------------------+------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+-------------+
```

My trouble is that the maximum "Assigned On" date for each user needs to be selected for each individual user and used for the actual join ...

Is there a clever way accomplish this in SQL?

Comment: So you've got Jon Skeet's old laptop?  Kewl!

Comment: @APC: Yep! Company thought he was spending too much time on StackOverflow... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT U.NetworkIdentifier, U.FirstName, U.LastName,
       H.HardwareName, H.SerialNumber
  FROM (SELECT UserID, MAX(AssignedOn) LastAssignment
          FROM HardwareAssignments
         GROUP BY UserID) AS T
  JOIN HardwareAssignments AS HA
       ON HA.UserId = T.UserID AND HA.AssignedOn = T.LastAssignment
  JOIN Users AS U ON U.ID = HA.UserID
  JOIN Hardware AS H ON H.ID = HA.HardwareID
 ORDER BY U.NetworkIdentifier;
```

The difference between this and Justin Niessner's answer is where the sub-query appears; here, I've created it in the FROM clause.  This pretty much guarantees that it is executed once.  When there's a correlated sub-query in the WHERE clause as in Justin's answer, it is possible that the optimizer will execute the sub-query once for each row - which is more expensive when the tables are big.  A really good optimizer might flatten things so that the two are equivalent.

Comment: +1 If the OP is able to get this version working, it'll perform far better than my post (for large data sets...and as long as the query optimizer doesn't flatten my query to work this way).

Comment: @Justing Niessner: Moved the accepted answer to this one based on the comment above. Please don't take it personally :)

Comment: +1 Tested this briefly, huge gain. However it should be noted that correlated query might perform better if outer query has high selectivity and tables are huge (although then it is easy to improve the above query by repeating the selection criteria on the inner query).

Comment: @Unreason: There are no selection criteria on the outer query. (This is for an export-to-csv function)

Answer (score 8):

```
select * from Users as u
inner join HardwareAssignments as ha
    on u.id = ha.userid
inner join Hardware as h
    on uh.hardwareid = h.id
where ha.AssignedOn = (select max(assignedon)
                       from HardwareAssignments as ha2
                       where ha.userid = ha2.userid)
```

That could get you close. Not sure if it's exact.

Comment: Adjust the columns to your needs, but the key part of the solution is the sub query.

Comment: Doh! *Bill feels a bit dumb now

Answer (score 0):

Use group by and max to filter the results of the join.

Comment: That only returns one row. I need one row per user.